# Resource cannot be found - MVC - passing in a guid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the default action that displays all items from a table:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var items = db.ProductSet.ToList();
    return View(items);
}
```

I added another action to the controller, that should display only items where a field equals a particular value:

```
 public ActionResult Details(string _key)
{
     System.Guid gkey = new Guid(_key);
     var items = db.ProductSet.Single(c => c.pKey == gkey);
     return View(items);
}
```

I call it with the following url:

```
http://localhost:57955/Details/ABBA9914-B55A-48A0-B436-00041FFAEAA7
```

and get an error: The resource cannot be found.

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Details/A88A9914-B56A-48A0-B436-00041FFAEAB5
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the Controller name in your url:

```
http://localhost:57955/Home/Details/ABBA9914-B55A-48A0-B436-00041FFAEAA7
```

Comment: I tried http://localhost:57955/Products/Details/ABBA9914-B55A-48A0-B436-00041FFAEAA7 now it says _key parameter is null. I debugged and _key turns out to be null, so the value does not get passed on. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: rename "_key" to "id". It might be your routing config

Comment: yeah. Use id unless you are making ajax call